# Html textbox visible with button click

Tags: javascript, html

How can i make a html textbox invisible and then it becomes visible when a user clicks on a button?
That button already has a js funtion to get values from an API but can it also make a textbox visible?
Btw i'm using getElementh by id.
The textbox is `<input type="textbox" id="city">`
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+toggle+field+button+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: `document.getElementById("city").hidden = someBoolean` where someBoolean will hide if true and show if false

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide and show a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578908/hide-and-show-a-text-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set display of your textbox to block, you can simply do if using onclick:

```
<button onclick="showHideTextBox()">Click Me to Show/Hide</button>
<input type="textbox" id="city">
<script>
    function showHideTextBox(){
      var x = document.getElementById("city");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
</script>
```

Instead of block you can add whatever display attribute value you want to add and inside showHideTextBox function you can add other logic which is needed for your api calls.

I found great answer about how to show hide elements in javascript: [How to show or hide an element:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21070237/4757316)

Comment: that is so inelegant and error prone if the display is not already set

Comment: I wasn't using it, but added it to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That button can also make the textbox visible. Add textbox's visible code to the button's event listener's function along with your existing fetch API function.

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // write textbox's show/hide function
   // call your existing function
})
```

To show/hide textbox you can toggle a class.